# How to set a custom title per language?

Tags: plugins, seo, multi-language, plugin-qtranslate, language

I am running Qtranslate for [my website](http://www.businessinstitute.nl/?lang=en).

I am very impressed by this plugin.
Now my only problem is that I cannot set a custom title and description for my homepage per language.
I can only setup one line for the title in the general settings for my website.

I have installed Qtranslate META where I can set a custom title and description per page, but my only problem is the homepage.

Any help would be realy appreciated how to fix this!

Thanks

Comment: Am not getting Exactly,What you are looking for?Just Tell Clearly

Comment: I would like to get a custom title and description for my homepage in English and I want a custom title and description for my site in Dutch. As you can see on my website there is a switch where you can switch per language.

No I can do all the above for all pages because of the plugin Qtranslate META. Except for the homepage because that is not a "page" as you know what I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a static page in this case:

> Settings **->** General **->** Fron Page Display: A static Page

Comment: I understand what you mean, but than I have a problem that there is a "post" in stead of the homepage slider.

Comment: Just add a template comment on top of your index page and then choose this template for your new static homepage.

Answer (score 2):

You may wanna try something like this :

> ```
>   <?php
>         $lang = qtrans_getLanguage();
>         if ($lang=="en") {
>               echo 'ENGLISH TEXT HERE';
>         } else if ($lang=="fr") {
>               echo 'FRENCH TEXT HERE';
>         } 
>   ?>
> ```